# How do I move files in the Share Documents section Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm doing some reorganization in a Shared Documents section of one of our Sharepoint sites.

One of the current folders is setup like this:

```
Documents -> Documents -> OnBase
```

What I'd like to do is either:

A) Move the Onbase Folder up to the same level as the root Documents folder

OR

B) Move all the files within the OnBase folder into the root Documents folder so I can simply rename it.

All my initial digging around Sharepoint is coming up with nothing.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a simple process, but not necessarily obvious.

On the Shared Documents page, click the arrow next to "Actions" and select "Open with Windows Explorer". This will open up a Windows Explorer window and allow you full options to copy, paste, add, delete as needed, even though the subtitle indicates it is only for adding files in.

For Sharepoint 2010 users, Go to Shared Documents Page, Click on Library tools->Library, Connect and Export Ribbon ( it is in the middle of the ribbon bar) and select the "Open with Windows Explorer".

Answer (score 3):

Without a Microsoft Windows client, movement may be difficult or impossible.

[With Microsoft's web interface alone – without third party products – can an end user move a folder in SharePoint Server 2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/46853/11050)

Not only folders. I also find it impossible to move a file.